# Gradle build issue on windows 10: Could not determine java version

Tags: gradle

I have cloned a github project which uses gradle for build. In my windows 10 system, I have installed gradle 6.8 and java is 11.0.7. When I run 'gradlew build' in IntelliJ console, I get following error:

```
>gradlew build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '11.0.7'.
```

How to get it working?

Comment: This is all the details I have.

Comment: If you run it with --debug flag, also try with --info and --stacktrace